# Spark Jobserver Unit Testing of jobs

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I want to write unit tests for spark jobs executed in the spark-jobserver.
This works fine unless I need to access the config e.g. check it for specific input values like:

```
Try(config.getString("myKey"))
      .map(x => SparkJobValid)
      .getOrElse(SparkJobInvalid("No value for myKey config param"))
```

The config is created as follows:

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config
val myConfig = ConfigFactory.parseString("key=value")
```

Then the job is run like:

```
MyJob.run(sqlCtx, myConfig))
```

This is the exception:

```
ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread driver-heartbeater  
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics._accumulatorUpdates of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1163)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics.readObject(TaskMetrics.scala:219)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1900)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deserialize(Utils.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:430)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1.apply(Executor.scala:430)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1.apply(Executor.scala:428)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:428)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:472)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:472)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics._accumulatorUpdates of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskMetrics.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1160)
        ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm with latest spark 1.6.1 this issue is gone. However the jobs do not seem to be impacted by this exception.